When we classify a polynomial as binomial, trinomial, etc., do we have to simplify it first?

When we classify a polynomial as binomial, trinomial, etc., do we have to simplify it first?

Example: $3x$ is a monomial. Then $2x + x$ is a binomial? Then $x + x + x$ a trinomial?
I have not read anywhere where they say you must simplify first.
If the above is correct then $1+1+1$ would be a trinomial?

Classifications of polynomials can only be done after they are simplified. Else it's meaningless

@Blue, thank you for you reply.

@Reuben: I didn't reply. (Well, now I have. :) I simply added the terminology tag.

@Blue, haha I thought something was wrong whne I tried to tag you.

@Gwen, thank you for your reply :D

Is $3+4$ a prime? Is $11+43$ even?
The two polynomials $3x$ and $x+x+x$ are not just related through a series of certain operations. They are the exact same polynomial. So any property that cares about the actual polynomial, rather than typographical details, will stay true for both of them simultaneously or neither of them simultaneously.
Some properties do care about typography. They usually specify something like "written as" or "in X form". Their value lies mostly in convenience and in shaping the mentality of the writer / reader (making certain operations easier to perform, making it easier to confirm certain properties hold, suggesting the next steps to take, etc.), rather than actual objective math. For instance,  "written as a square", where $x^2 + 2x + 1$ is not written as a square and $(x+1)^2$ is. But crucially they are both squares, because they are the same polynomial.
So $x+x+x$ is a monomial, but it's not written as a monomial.
